# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una función se ejecute cada x segundos en PHP?

Tags: php

me gustaría hacer que una función que lo que hace es obtener el valor de una API cada 100 segundos. Buscando por foros me he topado con el siguiente código, pero mi web literalmente se queda cargando. Lo dejo por aquí, un saludo.

PHP:

```
    function setInterval($f, $milliseconds)
{
    $seconds=(int)$milliseconds/1000;
    while(true)
    {
        $f();
        sleep($seconds);
    }
}

     setInterval(function(){
    if ($credits >= "2000") {
                    
    include './assets/php/app.php';
                

    }
    else {

    }
   }, 10000);
```

Comment: Mírate [ob_flush()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-flush.php) por si te sirve. Aunque tu script siga funcionando en el servidor teóricamente seguirá enviando los datos en cada ejecución de esa función. Pero ojo con los timeouts, deberás jugar tambien con [set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Deberías ir por el lado de los CRON Jobs. Te pasó link SO en inglés para ver algo al respecto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Si se necesita refrescar a través del navegador, no se puede hacer de esa forma, porque el navegador se quedará bloqueado hasta que el script termine su ejecución. Para hacer lo que pides tienes que usar otras tecnologías del lado del cliente, como [Ajax y programación asíncrona](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ajax). Si es un script del lado del servidor, si hay más opciones, desde un ciclo infinito, un [disparador de subproceso](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.popen.php) para no bloquear el proceso, o usando cron-jobs.

Comment: Yo te planteo mejor que mires reactohp. Hay formas de crear procesos independientes con intervalos regulares y mientras mantener ejecución. Echa un vistazo

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, por el momento voy a mirar lo de los CRON Jobs, y feliz año nuevo ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Configurando una tarea cron!

Supongamos que tu código corre en un archivo `codigo.php`, y que quisieses correrlo cada minuto

```
* * * * * /ruta_local/codigo.php &> /dev/null
```

Para correrlo cada 100 segundos debes recurrir a algún truco como el siguiente:

Cada 100 segundos se puede interpretar también como correrlo en estos tres instantes:

- 1 minuto (después de iniciar una corrida en cero (0) segundos) + 40
  segundos
- 3 minutos (después de iniciar una corrida en cero (0)
  segundos) + 20 segundos
- 5 minutos (corrida en cero (0) segundos)

De esa forma, puedes configurar 3 tareas cron en los minutos 1, 3 y 5, y pausando la ejecución los segundos adicionales con `sleep`

```
// Cada minuto después de una ejecución en cero, con sleep de 40 segundos
1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 * * * * sleep 40; php /usr/local/bin/run.php &> /dev/null

// Cada 3er minuto después de una ejecución en cero, con sleep de 20 segundos
3,8,13,18,23,28,33,38,43,48,53,58 * * * * sleep 20; php /ruta_local/codigo.php &> /dev/null

// Cada 5 minutos (ejecución en cero), sin sleep
0/5 * * * * php /ruta_local/codigo.php &> /dev/null
```

===============================================================

**Nota Importante**:

Descarta por completo cualquier uso de peticiones desde el cliente. Te daré al menos 4 razones:

1. No necesitas (ni vas a desear nunca) spamear tu servidor con peticiones automatizadas. Peor te irá mientras más clientes ejecuten peticiones.
2. Si tu cliente pasa a estar inactivo, se acabarán las peticiones y dejarás de procesar tu código
3. Si la conexión no es confiable, retrasos en las peticiones harán que las ejecuciones se lleven a cabo en plazos distintos a 100 segundos
4. Perderás el control de los tiempos de ejecución de tu código. Si la consulta llegase a tardar más de 100 segundos para procesarse, las peticiones no se frenarán y solo conseguirás saturar tu servidor. En tu servidor puedes contar con herramientas para monitorear la ejecución de tus scripts y evitar correrlos nuevamente si no ha terminado la ejecución previa.

Comment: Hola Anibal,
Voy a ponerlo en prueba, lo he marcado como resuelto por la sencillez con la que lo has expresado, muchas gracias y feliz año nuevo! Cualquier cosa te digo :D

Comment: ¡Excelente! Feliz Año para ti también! Comenta luego cómo te fue, por si hace falta mejorar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @low_aortical_supremassy, entiendo lo que quieres hacer pero tienes que entender que php es server-side que quiere decir esto que se ejecuta una vez del lado del servidor y después es enviado al usuario. en caso de que quieras hacer un llamado a una api solo una vez estaría bien, pero tu quieres hacerlo cada 100 segundos, para esto te recomiendo que lo hagas del lado del cliente, prueba utilizando fetch de js [Uso de Fetch: MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Entiendo que tu pagina web se queda cargando por siempre ya que nunca termina el loop lo que hace que no pueda o no termina nunca de generar el lado del cliente.